# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't map JavaScript source code of a nodejs module loaded through require()

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm trying to setup the environment for developing NodeJS app with the IntelliJ IDEA using the NodeJS plugin (I believe it works the same in WebStorm).

I have no problem running simple applications, but once I start to `require()` a module of my own, I end up with a problem: IDEA doesn't understand what is the source file of the required module and all the stacktraces for breakpoints inside my module look like this:

`unknown:0 // (this is my require()d module, but wrapped in an IIFE by nodejs module loader)
Module._compile(), module.js:460
Module._extensions..js(), module.js:478
...`

[image: debugger stack trace]

(as the source code is not picked up, I end up in my module with Step Inside/Step Over from my main file)

The code is really basic:

```
var m = require("./modulejs.js");
var test = new m.Test("Test");
test.printname();
```

and `modulejs.js` looks like this:

```
var Test = (function () {
    function Test(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Test.prototype.printname = function () {
        console.log("Test name: " + this.name); // I'm on this line in the screenshot above
    };
    return Test;
})();
exports.Test = Test;
```

The problem seems so basic to me that I'm quite sure it's some misconfiguration on my side.

I'm on Windows 7 using IDEA 14.1.4 and NodeJS plugin 141.1509, both of which seems to be the latest stable versions. I also tried different nodejs versions: 0.11.16 and 0.12.5 with the same behavior on both versions. It works with 0.10.36 as expected though.

Comment: your code runs fine for me - no exceptions, test name is printed as expected. And I can hardly imagine what can be misconfigured here - the Node.js Run configuration is trivial - just the path to node and file to run... Please create a new project with just 2 .js files and paste the code - can you run your code?

Comment: This is how I ended up with this code -- created an empty project and added these two files there. The code also runs fine for me, but I can't place breakpoints inside my module (`modulejs.js`), IDEA doesn't recognize them

Comment: I've modified the question a bit to make it a little bit more clear that the problem is not with the code, but with debugging it

Comment: works for me - I can put breakpoints in printname() and Test(), and they are successfully hit (using Node.js 0.10.x)

Comment: please attach a screenshot that shows up your issue. Are you talking about names displayed in Frames tab of Debugger tool window? To me, names are shown correctly when breakpoint is hit - 'Test.printname(), modulejs.js:6'

Comment: lena, I've just tried node.js 0.10.39 and it works as expected. So it seems the problem is IDEA 14.1 + nodejs 0.11+

Comment: lena, are you aware of that problem in JetBrains already? Any ticket I can follow?

Comment: This is an issue on my side too using IntelliJ 14.1.4 and 15 EAP on OS X Yosemite. With Node.js 0.10 and io.js 3.0 breakpoints work perfectly with Node.js 0.11 and 0.12 breakpoints on unknown lines are caused by module require calls.

Comment: @Hrundik I have logged this issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144144

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem. The solution is to use intellij Webstorm instead off intellij. It doesn't have this problem and probably downloads .js file from remote server (I am not sure about this). But I solved the problem this way. Hope this helps.